# Base64 encoded OpenType font-face using data URI,that dynamicaly input user from computer

Tags: base64, font-face, truetype

The user must upload ttf file,and I want to apply that font file for text,that's why I use base64 format in font-face,but something went wrong,and don't changed text font

https://jsfiddle.net/Meline222/xmeuqwp4/1/

```
var output = document.getElementById('output');
        var f = new FontFace("fingerpaint", `url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,${ret})`);
        console.log(dataURL)
        f.load().then(function(loaded_face) {
             output.style.fontFamily = "fingerpaint";
```